# Makefile Errors When Migrating from Old SDK to Vitis 2020.2 on a Custom Zynq-7000 Board

Tags: embedded, xilinx-edk

I am working on a camera project and we're using a custom Zynq-7000 board (xc7z030sbg485-3). I have followed Xilinx's official guidelines to migrate an old SDK project into Vitis 2020.2. However, when I try to build the platform, it fails with the following errors:

make[2]: *** [Makefile:66: standalone_libs] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:46: ps7_cortexa9_0/libsrc/standalone_v6_8/src/make.libs] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:18: all] Error 2

Full makefile:

```
            # Makefile generated by Xilinx.

            DRIVER_LIB_VERSION = 1.0
            PROCESSOR = ps7_cortexa9_0
            LIBRARIES = ${PROCESSOR}/lib/libxil.a
            BSP_MAKEFILES := $(wildcard $(PROCESSOR)/libsrc/*/src/Makefile)
            SUBDIRS := $(patsubst %/Makefile, %, $(BSP_MAKEFILES))
            BSP_SEQUENTIAL_MAKEFILES := ps7_cortexa9_0/libsrc/coresightps_dcc_v1_4/src/Makefile ps7_cortexa9_0/libsrc/cpu_cortexa9_v2_7/src/Makefile ps7_cortexa9_0/libsrc/devcfg_v3_5/src/Makefile ps7_cortexa9_0/libsrc/dmaps_v2_4/src/Makefile ps7_cortexa9_0/libsrc/gpiops_v3_4/src/Makefile ps7_cortexa9_0/libsrc/gpio_v4_3/src/Makefile ps7_cortexa9_0/libsrc/iicps_v3_8/src/Makefile ps7_cortexa9_0/libsrc/mipicsiss_v1_2/src/Makefile ps7_cortexa9_0/libsrc/qspips_v3_5/src/Makefile ps7_cortexa9_0/libsrc/scugic_v3_10/src/Makefile ps7_cortexa9_0/libsrc/scutimer_v2_1/src/Makefile ps7_cortexa9_0/libsrc/scuwdt_v2_1/src/Makefile ps7_cortexa9_0/libsrc/standalone_v6_8/src/Makefile ps7_cortexa9_0/libsrc/uartps_v3_7/src/Makefile ps7_cortexa9_0/libsrc/xadcps_v2_3/src/Makefile ps7_cortexa9_0/libsrc/xilffs_v4_0/src/Makefile ps7_cortexa9_0/libsrc/xilrsa_v1_5/src/Makefile
            BSP_PARALLEL_MAKEFILES := $(filter-out $(BSP_SEQUENTIAL_MAKEFILES),$(BSP_MAKEFILES))
            SEQ_SUBDIRS := $(patsubst %/Makefile, %, $(BSP_SEQUENTIAL_MAKEFILES))
            PAR_SUBDIRS := $(patsubst %/Makefile, %, $(BSP_PARALLEL_MAKEFILES))

            ifneq (,$(findstring win,$(RDI_PLATFORM)))
             SHELL = CMD
            endif

            all: 
                $(MAKE) --no-print-directory seq_libs
                $(MAKE) -j --no-print-directory par_libs
                $(MAKE) --no-print-directory archive
                @echo 'Finished building libraries'

            include: $(addsuffix /make.include,$(SUBDIRS))

            seq_libs: $(addsuffix /make.libs,$(SEQ_SUBDIRS))
                @echo 'Finished building libraries sequentially.'

            par_libs: $(addsuffix /make.libs,$(PAR_SUBDIRS))
                @echo 'Finished building libraries parallelly.'

            archive:
                arm-none-eabi-ar -r  $(LIBRARIES) $(wildcard $(PROCESSOR)/lib/*.o)

            clean: $(addsuffix /make.clean,$(SUBDIRS))
                rm -f ${PROCESSOR}/lib/libxil.a

            $(PROCESSOR)/lib/libxil.a: $(PROCESSOR)/lib/libxil_init.a
                cp -f $< $@

            %/make.include: $(if $(wildcard $(PROCESSOR)/lib/libxil_init.a),$(PROCESSOR)/lib/libxil.a,)
                @echo "Running Make include in $(subst /make.include,,$@)"
                $(MAKE) -C $(subst /make.include,,$@) -s include  "SHELL=$(SHELL)" "COMPILER=arm-none-eabi-gcc" "ARCHIVER=arm-none-eabi-ar" "COMPILER_FLAGS=  -O2 -c" "EXTRA_COMPILER_FLAGS=-mcpu=cortex-a9 -mfpu=vfpv3 -mfloat-abi=hard -nostartfiles -g -Wall -Wextra"

            %/make.libs: include
                @echo "Running Make libs in $(subst /make.libs,,$@)"
                $(MAKE) -C $(subst /make.libs,,$@) -s libs  "SHELL=$(SHELL)" "COMPILER=arm-none-eabi-gcc" "ARCHIVER=arm-none-eabi-ar" "COMPILER_FLAGS=  -O2 -c" "EXTRA_COMPILER_FLAGS=-mcpu=cortex-a9 -mfpu=vfpv3 -mfloat-abi=hard -nostartfiles -g -Wall -Wextra"

            %/make.clean: 
                $(MAKE) -C $(subst /make.clean,,$@) -s clean
```

From Xilinx's official training material, I understand that the purpose of the Makefile is to help automate the compilation process and it includes all the source code files for the project.

I would really appreciate any guidance on how to resolve these Makefile errors. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found standalone related makefile => "make[1]: *** [Makefile:46: ps7_cortexa9_0/libsrc/standalone_v6_8/src/make.libs] Error 2"

###############################################################################

## Copyright (C) 2011 - 2015 Xilinx, Inc. All rights reserved.

## Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy

## of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal

## in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights

## to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell

## copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is

## furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

## The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in

## all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

## THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR

## IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,

## FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL

## XILINX BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY,

## WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF

## OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE

## SOFTWARE.

## Except as contained in this notice, the name of the Xilinx shall not be used

## in advertising or otherwise to promote the sale, use or other dealings in

## this Software without prior written authorization from Xilinx.

###############################################################################

include config.make

CC=$(COMPILER)

AR=$(ARCHIVER)

CP=cp

COMPILER_FLAGS=

EXTRA_COMPILER_FLAGS=

LIB=libxil.a

CC_FLAGS = $(subst -pg, -DPROFILING, $(COMPILER_FLAGS))

ECC_FLAGS = $(subst -pg, -DPROFILING, $(EXTRA_COMPILER_FLAGS))

ifeq (($(notdir $(CC))) , arm-xilinx-eabi-gcc)

ECC_FLAGS += -nostartfiles\

-march=armv7-a \

-mfloat-abi=soft \

-mfpu=neon

endif

ifeq (($(notdir $(CC))) , arm-none-eabi-gcc)

ECC_FLAGS += -nostartfiles

endif

RELEASEDIR=../../../lib

INCLUDEDIR=../../../include

INCLUDES=-I./. -I${INCLUDEDIR}

OUTS = *.o

OBJECTS = $(addsuffix .o, $(basename $(wildcard *.c)))

ASSEMBLY_OBJECTS = $(addsuffix .o, $(basename $(wildcard *.S)))

INCLUDEFILES=*.h

libs: $(LIBS)

standalone_libs: $(LIBSOURCES)

echo "Compiling standalone"

$(CC) $(CC_FLAGS) $(ECC_FLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $^

$(AR) -r ${RELEASEDIR}/${LIB} ${OUTS}

profile_libs:

$(MAKE) -C profile COMPILER_FLAGS="$(COMPILER_FLAGS)" EXTRA_COMPILER_FLAGS="$(EXTRA_COMPILER_FLAGS)" COMPILER="$(CC)" ARCHIVER="$(AR)" libs

.PHONY: include

include: standalone_includes profile_includes

standalone_includes:

${CP} ${INCLUDEFILES} ${INCLUDEDIR}

profile_includes:

$(MAKE) -C profile COMPILER_FLAGS="$(COMPILER_FLAGS)" EXTRA_COMPILER_FLAGS="$(EXTRA_COMPILER_FLAGS)" COMPILER="$(CC)" ARCHIVER="$(AR)" include

clean:

rm -rf ${OBJECTS}

rm -rf ${ASSEMBLY_OBJECTS}

$(MAKE) -C profile COMPILER_FLAGS="$(COMPILER_FLAGS)" EXTRA_COMPILER_FLAGS="$(EXTRA_COMPILER_FLAGS)" COMPILER="$(CC)" ARCHIVER="$(AR)" clean